# Create jQuery plugin and than use its context

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

For example, i want to create Slider.

```
jQuery.fn.Slider = function(){ 
    var reset = function(){};
    var setValue = function(){};
};
```

than use it

`var slider = $('#slider').Slider();`

but i need to use it later, for ex. `slider.reset(); slider.setValue(50);...`

But i can't return object context in `fn.Slider`, i think that there is another method for solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to attach your methods to the object, not declare them as private scoped variables.

```
jQuery.fn.Slider = function(){ 
    this.reset = function(){};
    this.setValue = function(){};
};
```